# Chebyshev coefficients upper bounded by sup-norm of function?

Tags: chebyshev-polynomials

Let $T_k(x)$ be the [Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Definition) and consider the function
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty c_k \, T_k(x).
$$
Show that
$$
|c_k| \leq \|f\|_{[-1,1]}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of Chebyshev coefficients, we have that
$$
\begin{aligned}
|a_k|
&=
\left|
\frac{2}{\pi}
\int_{-1}^1
\frac{f(x) \, T_k(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\, dx
\right|
\\&\leq
\|f(x) \, T_k(x)\|_{[-1,1]}
\, 
\left|
\frac{2}{\pi}
\int_{-1}^1
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\, dx
\right|
\\&\leq
\|f(x)\|_{[-1,1]}
\end{aligned}
$$
where on the last line I used that $\|T_k(x)\|_{[-1,1]} = 1$ and
$$
\int_{-1}^1
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\, dx
$$
is the area $\frac{\pi}{2}$ of half the unit disk.